# Links made with link_to in rails mailer template are not clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my mailer I am forming a link as follows

```
class CustomerMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def magic_login_email
    customer = params[:customer]
    @customer_login_url =  magic_login_url(customer.authentication_token)

    mail(to: customer.email, subject: "Here's your login link")
  end
end
```

And I am using this in the template as follows

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Here's your login link</h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= link_to 'Log in now', @customer_login_url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I open this email in gmail I am not able to click the link. The link appears to be in text.
Can anyone help me with a solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact text that's rendered in the email? And what's the content of `@customer_login_url`?

Comment: Hey @JohnP, thanks for the reply

So,
```@customer_login_url = http://localhost:3000/magic_logins/g8rSJdnUf6DwPugmXDyo```

This is being rendered:

To login to the site, just follow this link: http://localhost:3000/magic_logins/g8rSJdnUf6DwPugmXDyo

Thanks for joining and have a great day!

Comment: So, instead of the `link_to` helper rendering the text wrapped in the URL, it's rendering the URL? Is this a text view or an HTML view? Because Rails mailers have both, and they work a bit differently (because text and HTML are different). FWIW, your tag looks correct so my guess would be that you're using a text view. What's the file name of your view?

Comment: It is an HTML view with the name as ```magic_login_email.html.erb```

Comment: Is the code you posted the entire view? Can you post the source code from the email you receive? Another thing to try is using byebug to inspect the process while Rails is running, so you can check that the variables are doing what you expect!

Comment: It turns out Gmail parses the emails going to spam to make the links appear in text

Comment: Aha - GMail is always helpful! Might be worth posting this as an answer to your own question, so other people in future with the same problem can find the answer more easily.